# org.json.JSONException: Value Error Android

Tags: android

I am pulling the data from the array I have assigned in the php file. I get an error pulling data from the Array output. The output is as follows:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value [{"program_dosya":"..."},{"program_dosya":"https:..."}, `{"program_dosya":"https:\/\/..."}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject`
```

I want to pull the "programfile" data assigned in array via android.
**PHP**

```
 $results[] = Array("program_dosya" => $programdosya);
```

**Android**

```
try {
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(result);

        JSONArray resultArray = jObj.getJSONArray("");
        for(int i = 0; i < resultArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = resultArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String name = obj.getString("programdosya");
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you need to iterate over the json array -

```
    // assuming you have string in this format, then all you have to do is
    String result = "[{\"program_dosya\":\"...\"},{\"program_dosya\":\"https:...\"}]";
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(result);
    for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject js = array.getJSONObject(i);
        String link = js.getString("program_dosya");
        System.out.println(link);
    }
```

Comment: {"program_dosya":"..."} I am printing out. I need the link part after program_dosya